# Template syntax error with end of recursion case

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Can someone tell me what is wrong with the syntax for the end of recursion specialization below?  I thought I was following all the rules.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename StreamType = std::ostream, StreamType& stream = std::cout>
class StringList {
    template <typename...> class AddStrings;
  public:
    template <typename... Args> void addStrings (Args&&... args) {AddStrings<Args...>()(args...);}
};

template <typename StreamType, StreamType& stream>
template <typename First, typename... Rest>
class StringList<StreamType, stream>::AddStrings<First, Rest...> : AddStrings<Rest...> {
public:
    void operator()(First&& first, Rest&&... rest) {
        // do whatever
        AddStrings<Rest...>::operator()(std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);
    }
};

template <typename StreamType, StreamType& stream>
template <>
class StringList<StreamType, stream>::AddStrings<> {
    friend class StringStreamList;
    void operator()() const {}  // End of recursion.
};

int main() {
    StringList<> stringList;
//  stringList.addStrings ("dog", "cat", "bird");
}
```

I don't understand the error message:

```
Test.cpp:22:11: error: invalid explicit specialization before '>' token
 template <>
           ^
Test.cpp:22:11: error: enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized
Test.cpp:23:39: error: template parameters not used in partial specialization:
 class StringList<StreamType, stream>::AddStrings<> {
                                       ^
Test.cpp:23:39: error:         'StreamType'
Test.cpp:23:39: error:         'stream'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the important bit:

`Test.cpp:22:11: error: enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized`

It means you can't define an explicit specialization of something that is a member of an unspecialized template.

```
class StringList<StreamType, stream>::AddStrings<> {
```

Here `AddStrings` is explicitly specialized, but `StringList` is not. That's not allowed.

Comment: So what is the workaround?  I just want to end the recursion.

Comment: Hoist the `AddStrings` class template out of the `StringList` one, so it isn't a member, and can be specialized independently.

Comment: Ok, I will do that if necessary.  But based on what you said, `template <> class StringList<std::ostream, std::cout>::AddStrings<> { void operator()() const {} };` should compile, right (even though it would only be a temporary solution)?  But that doesn't either.

Answer (score 0):

Though Jonhathan Wakely's suggestion works, for those who strongly prefer to keep such a class nested because it is simply not used anywhere else, I figured we can just insert a dummy template argument for `AddStrings`.  Now I've kept it an inner class, as I strongly prefer, and the following now compiles:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename StreamType = std::ostream, StreamType& stream = std::cout>
class StringList {
    template <typename, typename...> struct AddStrings;  // The first type is a dummy type.
  public:
    template <typename... Args> void addStrings (Args&&... args) {AddStrings<void, Args...>()(args...);}
};

template <typename StreamType, StreamType& stream>
template <typename T, typename First, typename... Rest>
class StringList<StreamType, stream>::AddStrings<T, First, Rest...> : AddStrings<T, Rest...> {
  public:
    void operator()(First&& first, Rest&&... rest) {
        // do whatever
        std::cout << first << ' ';
        AddStrings<T, Rest...>::operator()(std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);
    }
};

template <typename StreamType, StreamType& stream>
template <typename Dummy>
class StringList<StreamType, stream>::AddStrings<Dummy> {
  public:
    void operator()() const {}  // End of recursion.
};

int main() {
    StringList<> stringList;
    stringList.addStrings ("dog", "cat", "bird");
}
```